# GCE How to use ImageDataGenerator in google TPU

Tags: python, keras, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

I have a Keras model, but it's too big for my local PC and I'm trying to migrate to Google cloud to be able to use TPU.

The examples that I have seen uses in memory images to train the model with fit function.

I have thousands of images and also I want to use image augmentation. In my local model I use `ImageDataGenerator` and `fit_generator`.

How do I do this using the TPU?

I have several ideas,

1. To mount a bucket in the virtual machine
2. Copy the images to the disk of virtual machine and use `ImageDataGenerator` as I do in my local machine.

But I'm not sure and I feel that all of these methods are inefficient.

Is there a way to do it efficiently?

Comment: Is the question how to implement ImageDataGenerator & fit_generator? Or is your question more so “How can I mount a large amount of images in a Google Cloud Platform VM”? What do you mean by “How do I do this using the TPU?”

Comment: @Milad, the question is about if I can use fit_generator in the same way than fit. And if it is a good idea mount a large amount of images using fuse fs, I have the filling what it must be very slow. Or about is there another way to do it better.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re looking for read speed, GCP does offer [SSD’s](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd), which would be the fastest way for your machine to read the images. Local SSD’s do have a 3TB limit, so you may have to attach multiple to your VM depending on the number of images.

If you’re looking to reduce costs, mounting a [Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) with FuseFS is the way to go, but it would be the slowest option as the potential distance from the source is the greatest.

Google has a [great article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/) that explains the different options you have for storage. The article also has tables that lay out the different costs as well as speeds, & other great technical details about what each option offers.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow recently announced support for Keras on Cloud TPU's (as of 1.11) so your existing model with `fit_generator` should work, here is an [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/models/experimental/keras_colab/shakespeare_lstm.py) using `fit_generator` on a TPU

For the performance part of your question, once you have the model running on TPU you can use the [TPU profiler](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/cloud-tpu-tools) to determine if storage is a bottleneck. If storage is a bottleneck there are a number of ways around this, mostly optimizing the [input pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance)